# How to save sql statement on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to save my SQL statement on SQL Server instead of typing it into my C# code. My question is what should I save this SQL statement as? I have tried to save it as a table-valued function and stored procedure but failed in doing so. Is there any other way to save this in SQL Server ?

this is my statement:

```
DECLARE @PickupDate datetime
DECLARE @SendingID int
DECLARE @PickupCountryID int, @PickupPostalID int, @PickupStreetID int,  @PickupAdrID int;
DECLARE @DeliveryCountryID int, @DeliveryPostalID int,  @DeliveryStreetID int, @DeliveryAdrID int, @PickupType varchar(2) 
DECLARE @RouteID int, @RoutePartNo int
DECLARE @weekday varchar(50)
DECLARE caclulate_pickup_route CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
      SendingID, 
      PickupPostal.CountryID,
      PickupStreet.PostalID,
      PickupAdr.StreetID,
      PickupAdrID,
      PickupDate,
      PickupType,
      DeliveryPostal.CountryID,
      DeliveryStreet.PostalID,
      DeliveryAdr.StreetID,
      DeliveryAdrID
      FROM Sending
      INNER JOIN Adr AS PickupAdr ON PickupAdrID=PickupAdr.AdrID 
      INNER JOIN Street AS PickupStreet ON PickupAdr.StreetID=PickupStreet.StreetID
      INNER JOIN Postal AS PickupPostal ON PickupStreet.PostalID=PickupPostal.PostalID
      INNER JOIN Adr AS DeliveryAdr ON DeliveryAdrID=DeliveryAdr.AdrID
      INNER JOIN Street AS DeliveryStreet ON DeliveryAdr.StreetID=DeliveryStreet.StreetID
      INNER JOIN Postal AS DeliveryPostal ON DeliveryStreet.PostalID=DeliveryPostal.PostalID
      WHERE PickupRouteID=0 --and DeliveryDate = '2013-07-31' and DeliveryType = 'N'

OPEN caclulate_pickup_route
FETCH NEXT FROM caclulate_pickup_route INTO  @SendingID, @PickupCountryID,@PickupPostalID, @PickupStreetID, @PickupAdrID, @PickupDate, @PickupType,
                                    @DeliveryCountryID, @DeliveryPostalID, @DeliveryStreetID, @DeliveryAdrID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @weekday = DATENAME(weekday, dateadd(day,-1, @PickupDate))
SELECT @RouteID = RouteID, @RoutepartNo = RoutePartNo FROM RoutePartPart AS RoutePartPart WHERE
  PickupAreaGrpID IN (SELECT AreaGrpID AS PickupAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
 (CountryID=@PickupCountryID OR PostalID=@PickupPostalID OR (PostalID IN 
 (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE 
  Postal<=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID) AND 
  CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)) AND PostalIDto IN 
 (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE 
  PostalID=@PickupPostalID) AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE 
  PostalID=@PickupPostalID))) OR StreetID=@PickupStreetID OR AdrID=@PickupAdrID) AND DenyType=0) AND

  PickupAreaGrpID NOT IN 
 (SELECT AreaGrpID AS PickupAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
 (CountryID=@PickupCountryID OR PostalID=@PickupPostalID OR (PostalID IN 
 (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal<=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID) AND 
  CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)) AND PostalIDto IN 
 (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID) AND 
  CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID))) OR StreetID=@PickupStreetID OR AdrID=@PickupAdrID) AND DenyType=1) AND
  DeliveryAreaGrpID IN 
 (SELECT AreaGrpID AS DeliveryAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
 (CountryID=@DeliveryCountryID OR PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID OR (PostalID IN 
 (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal<=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID) AND 
  CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)) AND PostalIDto IN 
 (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID) AND 
  CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID))) OR StreetID=@DeliveryStreetID OR AdrID=@DeliveryAdrID) AND DenyType=0) AND
  DeliveryAreaGrpID NOT IN 
 (SELECT AreaGrpID AS DeliveryAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
 (CountryID=@DeliveryCountryID OR PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID OR (PostalID IN (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE 
  Postal<=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID) AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE 
  PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)) AND PostalIDto IN (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE 
  PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID) AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE
  PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID))) OR StreetID=@DeliveryStreetID OR AdrID=@DeliveryAdrID) AND DenyType=1) AND
  Pickup=1 AND(
    (@weekday = 'Monday' AND [Monday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Tuesday' AND [Tuesday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Wednesday' AND [Wednesday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Thursday' AND [Thursday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Friday' AND [Friday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Saturday' AND [Saturday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Sunday' AND [Sunday] = 1))AND

  Types LIKE '%'+@PickupType+'%'

Update Sending SET PickupRouteID=@RouteID, PickupRoutePartNo=@RoutePartNo WHERE SendingID=@SendingID

FETCH NEXT FROM caclulate_pickup_route INTO @SendingID, @PickupCountryID,@PickupPostalID, @PickupStreetID, @PickupAdrID, @PickupDate, @PickupType,
                                            @DeliveryCountryID, @DeliveryPostalID, @DeliveryStreetID, @DeliveryAdrID
END
CLOSE caclulate_pickup_route
DEALLOCATE  caclulate_pickup_route
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why stored procedure not working? What it says?

Comment: Yeah, i don't see a reason of this not saving as a SP

Comment: @Lahib use a stored procedure mate

Comment: Can you show us how are you trying to add as SP?

Comment: Seriously you should consider rewriting this code. It is wrong for so many reasons

Comment: i Actually found my issue right after posting the question. And i have it working now. Sorry guys!

Comment: It just don't let you to create SP or not working while using it?
If not working while using, then statement has something wrong.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk the problem is that the database i am working on is from 1990 and the guy who created the database did it very poorly. And i actually am reusing his existing code for calculating routes. I am just using it in .net4.0 instead of .net 2.0 :)

Comment: @Epsilon it didnt let me save it as a SP :)

Comment: @Lahib: *it didn't let me save it as a SP* - did you get an error? If so: ***what*** error?

Comment: `"Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1: We are so not letting you save THIS as a stored procedure.`? :)

Answer (score 0):

After Posting the question i figured out how to save this as a stored procedure.

This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Calculate_Delivery_Routes] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @DeliveryDate datetime
DECLARE @SendingID int
DECLARE @PickupCountryID int, @PickupPostalID int, @PickupStreetID int,  @PickupAdrID int;
DECLARE @DeliveryCountryID int, @DeliveryPostalID int,  @DeliveryStreetID int, @DeliveryAdrID int, @DeliveryType varchar(2)
DECLARE @RouteID int, @RoutePartNo int
DECLARE @weekday varchar(50)
DECLARE caclulate_delivery_route CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
      SendingID,
      PickupPostal.CountryID,
      PickupStreet.PostalID,
      PickupAdr.StreetID,
      PickupAdrID,
      DeliveryDate,
      DeliveryType,
      DeliveryPostal.CountryID,
      DeliveryStreet.PostalID,
      DeliveryAdr.StreetID,
      DeliveryAdrID
      FROM Sending
      INNER JOIN Adr AS PickupAdr ON PickupAdrID=PickupAdr.AdrID
      INNER JOIN Street AS PickupStreet ON PickupAdr.StreetID=PickupStreet.StreetID
      INNER JOIN Postal AS PickupPostal ON PickupStreet.PostalID=PickupPostal.PostalID
      INNER JOIN Adr AS DeliveryAdr ON DeliveryAdrID=DeliveryAdr.AdrID
      INNER JOIN Street AS DeliveryStreet ON DeliveryAdr.StreetID=DeliveryStreet.StreetID
      INNER JOIN Postal AS DeliveryPostal ON DeliveryStreet.PostalID=DeliveryPostal.PostalID
      WHERE DeliveryRouteID=0 --and DeliveryDate = '2013-07-31' and DeliveryType = 'N'

OPEN caclulate_delivery_route
FETCH NEXT FROM caclulate_delivery_route INTO @SendingID, @PickupCountryID,@PickupPostalID, @PickupStreetID, @PickupAdrID, @DeliveryDate, @DeliveryType,
                                              @DeliveryCountryID, @DeliveryPostalID, @DeliveryStreetID, @DeliveryAdrID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @weekday = DATENAME(weekday, dateadd(day,-1, @DeliveryDate))
SELECT @RouteID = RouteID, @RoutePartNo = RoutePartNo FROM RoutePartPart AS RoutePartPart WHERE
  PickupAreaGrpID IN (
  SELECT AreaGrpID AS PickupAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec 
  WHERE (CountryID=@PickupCountryID OR PostalID=@PickupPostalID OR (PostalID IN (
  SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal<=(SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  AND CountryID=(
  SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  ) AND PostalIDto IN (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=
  (SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  AND CountryID=
  (SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  )
  ) OR StreetID=@PickupStreetID OR AdrID=@PickupAdrID) AND DenyType=0) AND
  PickupAreaGrpID NOT IN (SELECT AreaGrpID AS PickupAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
  (CountryID=@PickupCountryID OR PostalID=@PickupPostalID OR 
  (PostalID IN 
  (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal<=
  (  SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  AND CountryID=
  (SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  ) AND PostalIDto IN 
  (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=
  (SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@PickupPostalID)
  )
  )
  OR StreetID=@PickupStreetID OR AdrID=@PickupAdrID) AND DenyType=1) AND

  DeliveryAreaGrpID IN 
  (SELECT AreaGrpID AS DeliveryAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
  (CountryID=@DeliveryCountryID OR PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID OR 
  (PostalID IN (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal<=
  (SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID) 
  AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  ) AND PostalIDto IN 
  (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=
  (SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  )
  ) OR StreetID=@DeliveryStreetID OR AdrID=@DeliveryAdrID) AND DenyType=0) 
AND  DeliveryAreaGrpID NOT IN 
  (SELECT AreaGrpID AS DeliveryAreaGrpID FROM AreaGrpSpec WHERE 
  (CountryID=@DeliveryCountryID OR PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID OR 
  (PostalID IN (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal<=
  (SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  ) AND PostalIDto IN 
  (SELECT PostalID FROM Postal WHERE Postal>=
  (SELECT Postal FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  AND CountryID=(SELECT CountryID FROM Postal WHERE PostalID=@DeliveryPostalID)
  )
  ) OR StreetID=@DeliveryStreetID OR AdrID=@DeliveryAdrID) AND DenyType=1) AND  Delivery=1 
 AND(
    (@weekday = 'Monday' AND [Monday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Tuesday' AND [Tuesday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Wednesday' AND [Wednesday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Thursday' AND [Thursday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Friday' AND [Friday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Saturday' AND [Saturday] = 1)
          OR (@weekday = 'Sunday' AND [Sunday] = 1))AND 
 Types LIKE '%'+@DeliveryType +'%'

UPDATE Sending SET DeliveryRouteID=@RouteID, DeliveryRoutePartNo=@RoutePartNo WHERE SendingID=@SendingID

FETCH NEXT FROM caclulate_delivery_route INTO @SendingID, @PickupCountryID,@PickupPostalID, @PickupStreetID, @PickupAdrID, @DeliveryDate, @DeliveryType,
                                              @DeliveryCountryID, @DeliveryPostalID, @DeliveryStreetID, @DeliveryAdrID

END
CLOSE caclulate_delivery_route
DEALLOCATE  caclulate_delivery_route
END
```

Comment: if you're rewriting the code and saving as an SP, you should take the opportunity to remove the cursor and replace with a single UPDATE statement. You also appear to have lots of extraneous SELECTs. I appreciate that you didn't write this code originally, but why not make it more performant and more maintainable.

Comment: @SteveFord  but i i remove the cursor how would i update multiple rows?? i said the same thing to my boss and he said that there is no need to optimize it :\

Comment: take a look at UPDATE FROM ... take a look at some of the examples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx including the ones with common table expressions